# tipfy nosetest ImportError: No module named fancy_urllib

Tags: google-app-engine, nosetests, tipfy

I am trying to run nosetest using tipfy and google app engine but I keep getting an import error:

From the google_appengine directory I execute the following command (directory contains dev_appserver.py):

```
nosetests /Users/me/Documents/python/project/ --with-gae --without-sandbox
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/nosetests", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==0.11.4', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/core.py", line 117, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 816, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/core.py", line 134, in parseArgs
    self.config.configure(argv, doc=self.usage())
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/config.py", line 323, in configure
    self.plugins.configure(options, self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 270, in configure
    cfg(options, config)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 93, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 161, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/nosegae.py", line 84, in configure
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 51, in <module>
    import fancy_urllib
ImportError: No module named fancy_urllib
```

I can load the tipfy hello_world project without any errors and I have other app engine projects on the same machine, all running fine.

Using a mac os x 10.6.6 and I have both nose and nosegae installed. I have also tried to execute the same command from within the /Users/me/Documents/python/project/ folder but I get the same result

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4552&can=1&q=fancy_urllib&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: GAE uses Python 2.5, not 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is my quick fix:

Modify this file "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py"

```
......
if version_tuple == (2, 4):
  sys.stderr.write('Warning: Python 2.4 is not supported; this program may '
                   'break. Please use version 2.5 or greater.\n')
#Start Change
#DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
DIR_PATH = "/usr/local/google_appengine"
#End Change

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'google', 'appengine', 'tools')
......
```

Works for me so far.

Comment: This did the trick! After having modified the code as you suggest I can run nosetests --with-gae --gae-lib-root=/usr/local/google_appengine and see that the testcase is successfull

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it with option:

```
--gae-lib-root=/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine
```

and please show Python sys.path.

Comment: I have tried using that option but with the same result - I will add sys.path to the original post

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem using Nose / NoseGAE.  I had no luck with trying various `--gae-lib-root` values, but I did eventually have luck patching `dev_appserver.py` (located in `/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/` in my MacOS install) as follows:

```
...
try:
  import distutils.util
except ImportError:
  pass

# ----- start of new code -----
import os, sys

DIR_PATH = '/usr/local/google_appengine'
EXTRA_PATHS = [
    DIR_PATH,
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3'),
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'django_0_96'),
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'),
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'ipaddr'),
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webob'),
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib'),
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'simplejson'),
    os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'graphy'),
]
sys.path = EXTRA_PATHS + sys.path
# ----- end of new code -----

import dummy_thread
...
```

This closely follows some code in `appcfg.py` (`fix_sys_paths()`) mentioned in [GAE issue ticket #3597](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3597).  I suspect the issue lies in how Nose sets up the execution path, although I can't prove so at the moment.

Comment: I will give it a try later today

Comment: I am not sure where to put the code you have pasted here, could you show me the full dev_appserver.py file?

Comment: On my MacOS system this edit is made to file /usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py.  Unfortunately, although it does permit the nose tests to run, it breaks the application, i.e. I am not able to run the application in the SDK.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: I was able to trace the problem down to how NoseGAE sets up the path (it was appending the gae-libs to the path, when it really needed to prepend).  I've cloned NoseGAE in a [github repository](https://github.com/trammell/NoseGAE); the download `nosegae-0.1.8-macos` works out of the box on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is because of a UI bug when you set up the "Python Path" in the Preferences of GoogleAppengineLuncher. It needs an Enter to confirm the setting:

```
    sudo port install python2.7
```

Then set the "Python Path" to

```
    /opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

**Enter to confirm**

[See here](https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-mac-launcher/issues/detail?id=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running stand alone scripts then before using any appengine stuff you gotta link to dirs

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib/')
if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (2016) GAE Python recommends loading the project libraries in the file at the root level entitled "appengine_config.py".

Thus, if you are still facing some obnoxious issues, pls make sure to also add the os dir path to load the library folder "lib" (as can be seen in my code below):

```
"""`appengine_config` gets loaded when starting a new application instance."""
import os
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
# insert `lib` as a site directory so our `main` module can load
# third-party libraries, and override built-ins with newer
# versions.
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

After I did the above, I was able to run my tests successfully from IntelliJ (PyCharm).
Furthermore, please notice my test settings setup on intelliJ (PyCharm)

[image: IDE Settings]

Hope the above can help some Python GAE devs since I had some challenges in getting the NoseGAE simple setup to work. Take care!